# WebApi HttpGet route is not returning Content-Length response header for HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ftpwebrequest

I have a WebApi endpoint that gets an FTP file that is an mp4, and returns it. For some reason, the `Content-Length` response header is not getting set, which I suspect is causing my html5 video to not have the controls work properly, as the user is unable to seek.

Html:

```
<video controls src="api/my-ftp-file.mp4"></video>
```

WebApi:

```
[Route("api/{fileName}")]
[HttpGet]

public HttpResponseMessage FtpFile(string fileName)
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");

    var fullFilePath = "ftp://my-ftp-server/" + fileName;

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullFilePath);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Credentials = credentials;
    var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    // get content length (since response.ContentLength from above is -1)
    FtpWebRequest request2 = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullFilePath);
    request2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
    request2.Credentials = credentials;
    var response2 = (FtpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
    var contentLength = response2.ContentLength; // this DOES provide a value

    var ret = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    ret.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    ret.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4");
    // I've also tried ret.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength
    ret.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", contentLength.ToString());

    return ret;
}
```

My html5 video tag plays the video, altho, if you drag the ticker to seek to another point in the video, nothing happens. I suspect it's b/c the Content-Length in my Chrome Network tab is missing:

[image]

Why isn't Content-Length being sent along with the request?

Answer (score 0):

Because you send your response as "chunked" (**Transfer-Encoding**: chunked).
See [wikipedia: transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Should it not be chunked? If so, how do I set that? I bet that's why my video player controls aren't working properly.